# Using events in Jquery dragtable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use the events shown here?

http://jebaird.com/2010/12/29/dragtable-a-jquery-ui-widget-to-re-arrange-table-columns-via-drag-and-drop.html

I want to get the order of the columns everytime they are reordered.
I have tried this, but no results

```
var drag = $('#members_list').dragtable();

drag.on('change',function(){
    console.log("success")
})
```

Comment: "I have tried"... continue...

Comment: `var drag = $('#members_list').dragtable();

drag.on('change',function(){
    console.log("success")
})`

Comment: `dragtable` should be `draggable`

Comment: No, with `dragtable`  the plugin works. The problem is how to use the events described in the link I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind i found the answer

```
var drag = $('#members_list').dragtable();

drag.on('dragtablestop',function(){
   console.log("Success")
})
```